# How to write a query for grouping records in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to get all the users count based upon the created at

```
   User.group("Date(created_at)").count
```

It will give me a output like

```
 {Wed, 03 Aug 2011=>25, Thu, 04 Aug 2011=>22, 06 Aug 2011=>4, Sun, 07 Aug 2011=>6, Mon, 08 Aug 2011=>5}
```

I want to have an array something like:-

```
 [25,22,0,4,5]  // zero is for the dates when no record is there for that date.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@foo = User.group(:created_at).count` will give you your users grouped by their created_at date.

As you mentioned you'll get a hash of `{:date => count}`'s

You could then look at `@foo.values` (to get your count array) `[25,22,0,4,5]`, or iterate over it like

```
@foos.each_pair do |date, count|
  puts "#{date}: #{count}"
end
```

**EDIT** I now understand what you were trying to ask.

You could do something like this

```
start_date = Date.today - 7.days
end_date = Date.today
@foo = User.group("DATE(created_at)").where(:created_at => start_date..end_date).count
counts = (start_date..end_date).map{ |d| @foo[d] || 0 }
```

Comment: awesome.. But there were few minor tweeks to get the exact format. Improved your answer..Check this. my console outputs http://cl.ly/1p1F0802393i1L363w23  Upvoted and accepted. :)